# Encoding JSON in UTF-16 or UTF-32

Tags: json, unicode, character-encoding

The [JSON RFC, section 2.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5), says in part:

> To escape an extended character that is not in the Basic Multilingual
> Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence,
> encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.  So, for example, a string
> containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E) may be represented as
> "\uD834\uDD1E".

Assume I have a valid reason to encode JSON as UTF-16BE (which is allowed).  When doing so, is it still necessary to escape characters that are not in the Basic Multilingual Plane?  E.g., instead of this:

```
00 5C 00 75 00 44 00 38 00 33 00 34 00 5C 00 75 00 44 00 44 00 31 00 45
  \     u     D     8     3     4     \     u     D     D     1     E
```

which is the 24-byte UTF-16BE byte sequence for `\uD834\uDD1E`, is it legal to do this:

```
D8 34 DD 1E
```

i.e., use the 4-byte UTF-16BE values directly?

Similarly, if I were to encode the same JSON string as UTF-32BE, could I simply use the code-point value directly:

```
00 01 D1 1E
```

?

Comment: Good question. I suspect that whatever the spec says, in the end it comes down to the support of whoever is parsing the JSON.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes, you can write the UTF-16 values directly. Support: the RFC paragraph you quoted explains how to escape arbitrary Unicode *if you have decided to escape it*. However, earlier in that same section, the RFC says

> ***All*** Unicode characters ***may*** be placed within the quotation
>   marks *except for the characters that must be escaped*: quotation
>   mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through
>   U+001F).
>
> Any character ***may*** be escaped.  If the character is in the
>   Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be 
>   represented as a six-character sequence...

(Emphasis added.)

To me, this says that only `"`, `\` and control characters ***must*** be escaped, and that any other Unicode characters **may** be placed as-is directly into the JSON text (in whatever UTF form you are using). It also says to me that even if you're encoding as UTF-8, you don't need to use the `\uXXXX` form for any Unicode character other than `"`, `\`, and control characters.

(As an aside, this does make me wonder whether the `\uXXXX` form is actually useful for anything other than control characters. As the other poster said, it probably comes down to what your JSON parser actually supports.)

Comment: +1. `\u` form has more use for JSONP than straight JSON, since (a) you can't be sure what `charset` the containing page is using and setting `charset` in the `Content-Type` of a `<script>` is unreliable; and (b) the characters U+2028 and U+2029 are illegal in JavaScript (and hence JSONP) - it's a bit of an oversight that JSON allows them.

Comment: @bobince JSON is not only for communicating with javascript, it often used to communicate between systems implemented in other languages, therefore replicating all the limitations of javascript is counter-productive.  is '\U+2028' really forbidden in javascript strings? I can see that it would be harmful in source code between identifiers but in string literals it should be harmless.

Comment: Yes, U+2028 (and U+2029) is forbidden in JavaScript string literals, they're defined to be equivalent to a newline. If you're writing a JSON output library IMO it makes sense to replicate the limitations of popular languages to maximise interoperability.

Comment: @Jasen I mean... it is Java Script Object Notation.  If it can't be used as-is for javascript objects, well, you've got a naming problem at the very least. Fundamentally, it's a POLA issue.

Answer (score -4):

There is one idea we explored and it got worked in Azure Datafactory. Convert the encoding format to US-ASCII in the sink part(Json File). Source remains the same REST API Link:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good answer, it is always helpful for the user to add a few line of code. It is also better to upload an image directly into the question, since link addresses  may change over time.