# What is the valid in json but invalid in yaml1.2

Tags: python, json, yaml

Lots of people believe that the yaml1.2 is the superset of json. But there seems some proof that it isn't. However,i have trouble in finding these examples.(i want to use json.loads()and yaml.safe_loads in Python and i hope to see that jsonloads works well but yamlloafs throw an error). Would there be examples?

I know that in yaml1 1e2 will be consider as str but number in json.
So i want to find exception in yaml1.2 too

Comment: YAML is very different from JSON, so it's not clear what "superset" would mean in this context. Do you mean there's data that can be represented in YAML that can't be represented in JSON?

Comment: "YAML a strict superset of JSON" (as of the [specs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/), chapter 1.2 YAML History) simply means, simply speaking, that the JSON syntax is declared to be an alternative spelling for YAML, thus also valid YAML, and a YAML parser must be able to process it

Comment: @JonSG `jq -nc '{"a": 1e2}'` outputs `{"a":1E+2}`, `yq -n '{"a": 1e2}'` outputs `a: 1e2`. From YAML's point of view, both are the identical document, using different representations.

Comment: @JonSG Maybe it implements an earlier YAML spec (JSON was included with YAML 1.2, published in 2009).

Comment: @pmf Latest version of pyyaml --> `print(yaml.safe_load(io.StringIO('{"a": 1e2}')))` results in `{'a': '1e2'}` Though I see that the OP posted this same example and I somehow missed that they did making my comment redundant

Comment: I see also from the documentation that `pyyaml ` is only `1.1` compatible.

Comment: @JonSG I can't speak for Python or any of its packages, esp. not for how up to date they are or how consistently they adhere to specifications. I've just shown that the superset claim is part of the specifications since 2009, and that modern parsers in fact do implement them.

Comment: it's a question of a ctf game,you should solve it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In JSON, if you want to escape a Unicode character not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, you need to encode a UTF-16 surrogate pair ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38463038/why-does-json-encode-utf-16-surrogate-pairs-instead-of-unicode-code-points-direc)).

The YAML spec does not explicitly allow this, instead it allows for 32bit escape sequences (starting with `\U`). Hence, the following JSON

```json
{ "x": "\uD834\uDD1E" }
```

loads differently with a conforming JSON implementation than it does with a YAML implementation. The YAML implementation would possibly yield a string with two Unicode character from the surrogate block in it – which is allowed and legal since these are, as per Unicode spec, unassigned code points. Some implementations, specifically Windows-centric ones, may yield an error instead since the Windows API internally uses UTF-16 and thus cannot represent code points from the surrogate block.

Valid YAML evaluating to the same string would be

```yaml
{ "x": "\U0001d11e" }
```