Do surrogate pairs in JSON really have two interpretations?
The official JSON standard (ECMA-404, 2e, 2017-Dec) states the following about Unicode surrogate pairs:

However, whether a processor of JSON texts interprets such a surrogate pair as a single code point or as an explicit surrogate pair is a semantic decision that is determined by the specific processor.

What exactly is meant by this sentence?
Note that the same document states earlier:

Any code point may be represented as a hexadecimal escape sequence. The meaning of such a hexadecimal number is determined by ISO/IEC 10646. If the code point is in the Basic Multilingual Plane [...]. [...] To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character may be represented as a twelve-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair corresponding to the code point.

This wording is poor and confusing: If the standard forces a semantic interpretation of UTF-16 – because

it only allows Unicode escape sequences \uhhhh of exactly 4 hex digits (ie: 2 bytes) and
it mentions surrogates

– in which Unicode code points above the basic multilingual plane (BMP) are represented as two 2-byte code units instead of just one, why doesn't it mention UTF-16 earlier (immediately after its mention of ISO/IEC 10646 and before discussing BMP characters) instead of within the text about non-BMP characters? (Surely UTF-16 is implied for BMP code points as well. It is unlikely that the standard was meant to allow for documents without non-BMP code points to follow a non-UTF-16 character encoding.)
Back to the earlier sentence about interpreting surrogate pairs: If I now understand it correctly, it leaves it open to the JSON processor whether to (a) keep a sequence of 2-byte code units in JSON as an equally long sequence of code units vs (b) convert it into a potentially shorter sequence of code points.
But that's just like saying that a JSON processor can store a number as a double vs as a string after reading it in from a JSON value – not such a deep statement. Note also that the same standards document emphasizes that it doesn't impose a particular semantic interpretation on any JSON value (though the text "The meaning of such a hexadecimal number is determined by ISO/IEC 10646." seems to lay out a partial exception). It is also telling that RFC 8259 contains no wording analogous to the quoted sentence about surrogates.
Or is there more depth to the quoted sentence?

There is an answer here if you read between the lines: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38463038/674039

@wim I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but perhaps you can turn it into an answer? By the way, I don't think there is any inherent semantic ambiguity (though any JSON parser can choose to keep the two components separate I guess -- though no obvious use cases come to mind).

"JSON allows only Unicode escape sequences \uhhhh of exactly 4 hex digits (ie: 2 bytes). This (and the standard's mention of surrogates) implies UTF-16 ..." - it is not implied, it is explicitly stated in the sentence just before the one you quoted: "To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character may be represented as a
twelve-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair corresponding to the code point."

@RemyLebeau See my edit just now.

Your edit makes your question even more confusing to understand. However, a \uhhhh sequence represents a single UTF-16 code unit. Characters in the BMP use one code unit. Characters outside the BMP use 2 code units. Sure, the wording is confusing, but the semantic is as simple as that.

@RemyLebeau I'm actually deeply familiar with Unicode. The beginning of the JSON standard's wording makes it sound like \uhhhh is only about Unicode escape sequences, which could be for any of its many encodings. But all of a sudden the standard mentions UTF-16, only when discussing non-BMP characters, even though \uhhhh-escapes always represent UTF-16 code units. It ends with what I believe is a nonsensical statement about the "interpretation" of surrogates. But my question was worded in a way that somewhat reduces the "judgmental" aspect and invites other possible interpretations.

I interpret it as "the resulting list of values depends on the processor".
If you have a JSON string "d\ud83d\ude00b", in JS it should be deserialized to 4 sixteen-bit values like 0x64 0xd83d 0xde00 0x62. The parser has to keep the two components separate because JS strings consist of 16-bit values. Similarly with Java.
However, another engine may deserialize it to 3 thirty-two-bit values like 0x64 0x1f600 0x62. Technically they represent the same Unicode text, though.

Related: The WTF-8 encoding decode from potentially ill-formed UTF-16 to code points and vice versa

From what I see, the JSON standard specifically states that strings represent Unicode codepoints, and escape sequences represent UTF-16 codeunits. So ultimately "d\ud83d\ude00b" has to represent U+0064 U+1F600 U+0062, however the processor chooses to store that data, whether as UTF-16 (0x0064 0xD83D 0xDE00 0x0062), UTF-8 (0x64 0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x80 0x62), etc.

In proper UTF-8 a surrogate pair is treated as one and is converted to 4 bytes. If each component is converted to 3 bytes (6 bytes in total) the result is CESU-8.
