# How do JSON parsers encode unicode characters not in the basic multilingual plane?

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, xojo

I'm writing a JSON parser in Xojo. It's working apart from the fact that I can't figure out how to encode and decode unicode strings that are not in the basic multilingual plane (BMP). In other words, my parser dies if encounters something greater than `\uFFFF`.

The specs say:

> To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane,
>   the character may be represented as a twelve-character sequence,
>   encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair corresponding to the code point. So
>   for example, a string containing only the G clef character (U+1D11E)
>   may be represented as "\uD834\uDD1E". However, whether a processor of
>   JSON texts interprets such a surrogate pair as a single code point or
>   as an explicit surrogate pair is a semantic decision that is
>   determined by the specific processor.

What I don't understand is what is the algorithm to go from `U+1D11E` to `\uD834\uDD1E`. I can't find any explanation of how to "encode the UTF-16 surrogate pair corresponding to the code point".

For example, say I want to encode the smiley face character (`U+1F600`). What would this be as a UTF-16 surrogate pair and what is the working to derive it?

Could somebody please at least point me in the correct direction?

Comment: "*what is the algorithm to go from `U+1D11E` to `\uD834\uDD1E`*" - [UTF-16](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), just as the JSON spec says. You do know how UTF-16 works in general, don't you? If not, read its well-documented algorithm. In this case, UTF-16 encodes codepoint U+1D11E as two code units 0xD834 and 0xDD1E, which JSON then encodes as-is in `\uXXXX` string format. The UTF-16 surrogate pair for codepoint U+1F600 is 0xD83D 0xDE00, so `\uD83D\uDE00` in JSON

Comment: I read the linked article on Wikipedia - it was very helpful. I will answer my own question with an example for future reference for others. Thank you for checking my maths.

Comment: You have no need to actually make this conversion. https://stackoverflow.com/q/11641983/209139

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taken from the Wikipedia article linked by Remy Lebeau in the comments above ([link](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16)):

> To encode U+10437 () to UTF-16:
>
> Subtract 0x10000 from the code point, leaving 0x0437. For the high
>   surrogate, shift right by 10 (divide by 0x400), then add 0xD800,
>   resulting in 0x0001 + 0xD800 = 0xD801. For the low surrogate, take the
>   low 10 bits (remainder of dividing by 0x400), then add 0xDC00,
>   resulting in 0x0037 + 0xDC00 = 0xDC37. To decode U+10437 () from
>   UTF-16:
>
> Take the high surrogate (0xD801) and subtract 0xD800, then multiply by
>   0x400, resulting in 0x0001 × 0x400 = 0x0400. Take the low surrogate
>   (0xDC37) and subtract 0xDC00, resulting in 0x37. Add these two results
>   together (0x0437), and finally add 0x10000 to get the final decoded
>   UTF-32 code point, 0x10437.